# System freezes when viewing HTML5 content

Tags: nvidia, chrome, freeze, kernel-panic

My system freezes totally and immediately any time I view HTML5 video or audio on my Linux (OpenSUSE 13.2 x64) system using a WebKit-based browser (Chrome, Chromium, Opera all do it) of any kind. Flash works fine, but I hate flash. One time I actually got a kernel panic message from the Nouveau drivers, but I can't find anything in the logs about any error or failure.

When the system is frozen, it doesn't respond to any input and the audio  starts looping the last few seconds of output.

Are there any system settings or kernel flags that I can set to enable more logging? Or any specific logs I should look for?

I'm using a self-built system with a Core i7 4790, GeForce GTX 760, and 16GB RAM. I'm dual-booting between OpenSUSE 13.2 and Windows 8.1, each on separate SSDs. Incidentally, Windows has no issues whatsoever.

I've tried Nouveau and the NVidia proprietary drivers with no effect on the freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Google Chrome with the argument `--disable-gpu`. It should help you if the problem is related to the graphics card and its drivers.

If you want to see the logs while the system is frozen, log in to the system with ssh before of to run the browsers and look the logs. If the ssh session is also frozen then probably the kernel crashed.

Comment: When running Chrome with the disable GPU argument, it no longer freezes but also no video displays; audio plays and things like the YouTube video UI and annotations show but over a black rectangle. On a side note, when it does freeze, it now appears to consistently kernel panic rather than sit there frozen, but I can't find a crash dump. It does appear to be Nouveau from what I could see before reboot. If I can get a crash dump or at least a log, then I can report the issue to the Nouveau team. Any idea where I might find a dump?

Comment: Use `journalctl`: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Journal